# How can I extract this JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I have the following code:

```
var _initCarousel = function () {
    _carouselIndicators.empty();

    _steps.each(function(index, element) {
        var li = $( '<li></li>' );
        $(li).click(function () {
            _steps.filter(':visible').hide();
            _carouselIndicators.children('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(element).show();
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        _carouselIndicators.append( li );
    });

    _carouselIndicators.children().first().addClass('active');
};
```

How can I extract the inner function on the same level as `_initCarousel`. The problem is the element parameter. How to pass it into the inner function?

The goal is better readability and maintainability.

---

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    </ol>

    <div class="step" style="background-image: url(./images/p2.jpg);">
        //...
    </div>

    <div class="step" style="background-image: url(./images/p1.jpg);">
        //...
    </div>
```

Thats the relevant HTML. And that's how I get the variables:

```
    _steps = $('.step');
    _carouselIndicators = $('.carousel-indicators');
```

Comment: Which inner function? I see two of them

Comment: @Bergi The function in question is the innerst one. As I said, the problem is the element parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really.  `element` comes from the parent scope.  If you extract the inner function to it's own function at a higher level, it won't have access to that parent scope.

Plus, you aren't the one calling the function.  It's called as a jQuery click handler so you can't pass additional parameters to it directly.

There are lots of work-arounds that either involve storing the `element` somewhere else or involve creating some sort of function stub that will pass it in.  Both seem to me like they would make your code less readable not more readable.

In javascript, there are often significant advantages to using inline anonymous functions that have access to their parent scope and can significantly simplify your code.  This is a readable and maintainable structure and is used extensively in major javascript projects (such as jQuery).  I'd be curious why you think this isn't readable or maintainable?  Once you really understand them, closures like this are a powerful tool in javascript that can help you write cleaner code, not something to be avoided.

---

For example, here's a work-around that stores the `element` in a place you can access it using `.data()`.  I'd personally rather keep the original structure of using `element` from the parent scope rather than the extra steps of having to store/retrieve it.

```
var processCarouselClick = function() {
     _steps.filter(':visible').hide();
     _carouselIndicators.children('.active').removeClass('active');
     $(this).data("element").show();
     $(this).addClass('active');
}

var _initCarousel = function () {
    _carouselIndicators.empty();

    _steps.each(function(index, element) {
        var li = $( '<li></li>' ).data("element", element);
        $(li).click(processCarouselClick);
        _carouselIndicators.append( li );
    });

    _carouselIndicators.children().first().addClass('active');
};
```

Of course, if we saw the larger context of your code to know what `element` actually is, we might be able to use DOM traversal to find it directly without storing it, but with the limited portion of code you've included, that's just a guess.

Comment: Well, it isn't not readable. But the concern of `_initCarousel` is to initialize the `li`'s. Put them into the DOM, assign their class and click handler. But this concern is split in half, by the actual click handler. But I guess this is just something I'm not used to, from my main language. And thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes - yes, it is something to get used to in Javascript (I remember thinking the same thing when I went from C++ to JS).  When you get used to the style, you will discover many programming advantages of having access to the parent scope, not having to declare another external function, seeing the actual click code in place, etc... and then you will miss having this feature in your other languages.